# Changing SDK location in Android Studio:Whitespaces in directory location

Tags: android, sdk

I am using android API level 22.But this location was copied from another machine and it is in my E: drive.I have API level 23 installed in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

But when i try to change the location to the above one, i get the following message:

```
Android SDK location should not contain whitespace,as this can cause problem with the native tools.
```

How do i change the SDK location to the above location without having the issue of whitespaces.

Comment: Try replacing whitespace with `%20`

Comment: % is shown as a illegal character.

Comment: The error clearly states, not to have white spaces. You should move the Android directory to some path with no spaces, you could have underscores if you want.

Comment: @EricB. The issue with that approach is that if i update my sdk in the future i would have to again copy the updates to the new location.I read somewhere that Program Files (x86) can be written as PROGRA~2.Will that work?.

Comment: I don't know about PROGA~2. But i think if you move the sdk to another directory then future updates will be installed to the new directory.

Comment: for Android Studio, you can set the path manually in the file: %Home%\.AndroidStudio2.1\config\options\jdk.table.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change location to (in my case its located here)

```
C:\Users\johnrao\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Try **Copying files in these folders** or delete files and reinstall from the **sdk manager**

Comment: The problem is what i have mentioned.The space between Program and Files.The space between Files and (x86) is also a issue.

Answer (score 14):

Here is how I fixed this issue.  No need to relocate directories.

On Windows, open an elevated command prompt.  Hit the Win key, type 'cmd', right click on the cmd prompt search entry, select 'Run as Administrator".

In the command prompt, execute:  mklink /J C:\Program-Files "C:\Program Files"

This will create a space-free directory path that points into the same directory as used by space-friendly software.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks :D

Comment: really useful for other problems as well! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is located in your home directory, as it seems to be by default, you can open up a Command Prompt to see what the "DOS" version of your home directory looks like:

```
dir /x C:\Users
```

Look at the 4th column, and it should show the valid 8-character (max) directory name that can be used in the Android Studio path.