# Not able to Install Android SDK Platform

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

React Native Documentation Recommends SDK Platform Android 6.0 (Marshmallow), When I try to install, it is dim, and I am not able to download and install. See image here:
[image: See Image Here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing SDK location in Android Studio:Whitespaces in directory location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127431/changing-sdk-location-in-android-studiowhitespaces-in-directory-location)

Comment: I had same problem, edit the android SDK location to correct path.

Answer (score 0):

the sdk path can not include space!!!!

so you can download the sdk in D:\sdk

Comment: Doesn't necessarily need to be in `D:/sdk`. It could be anywhere, as long as there's no space in the path

Answer (score 0):

change directory to android sdk directory, then go deeper into tools/bin:

run following command, any meaningful error must get visible in terminal, so you can detect the impediments against downloading platform:

> sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-23"

Answer (score 0):

Create a non-spaced directory for example `C:\AndroidSdk` and move the content of `C:\Users\Kashif Nazir\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` to the new folder. Then, in Android Studio SDK Manager, change the SDK location to `C:\AndroidSdk`. Now, you'll be able to download and save different SDKs.